Is it possible to copy views from one Azure hosted SQL DB to another?
It appears that with non Azure SQL DBs you can right click the DB and then go to 'Tasks' to be able to script out your views.  I don't have that option with my Azure SQL.  I can always script each one individually, however, was hoping for a quicker way to do it as I have 40-50 views.

Something like this   https://dataedo.com/kb/query/azure-sql/list-views-with-their-scripts

Does sp_helptext exist/work in Azure?  If so, set SSMS to return results as text instead of table and execute:
exec sp_helptext 'schema.objectname'

It should return the create script.  (Technically it returns a table with a single column named [Text] with a row for each line of the script.)
It works with views, stored procs, functions and triggers.

Looks like sp_helptext is not supported for these DBs.

The response by Dijkgraaf gives the definition of the view which will allow me to create a larger script to recreate my views. https://dataedo.com/kb/query/azure-sql/list-views-with-their-scripts
